# Body of GCM notification always displays as <missing message content> when using PushSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-cloud-messaging, pushsharp

I'm using PushSharp version 4.0.1 and currently when ever I send out a notification the title displays fine but the body of the message always displays as ''. If I send a test message directly to GCM from Postman with out using PushSharp the content displays fine. Below is how I'm structuring the message body. Any ideas would be great!

```
   gcmBroker.QueueNotification(new GcmNotification
   {
       RegistrationIds = new List<string>
       {
         token
       },
       Data = JObject.Parse("{ \"title\" : \""+ message.PatientFirstName +" "+ message.PatientLastName + ". " + message.GlucoseMeasurement.TrendArrow +"\"," +
                            " \"body\" : \""+ message.GlucoseMeasurement.ValueInMgPerDl + "at" + message.GlucoseMeasurement.Timestamp + "\"," +
                            " \"icon\" : \"icon\"," +
                            " \"color\" : \"#FF4081\"}")
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually ended up figuring it out after digging further into the GCM docs. I was trying to send a data notification unknowingly since I was using the `Data`param. The code should have looked like this instead...

```
            gcmBroker.QueueNotification(new GcmNotification
            {
                RegistrationIds = new List<string>
                {
                    token
                },
                Notification = JObject.Parse("{ \"title\" : \"" + message.PatientFirstName + " " + message.PatientLastName + ". " + message.GlucoseMeasurement.TrendArrow + "\"," +
                                     " \"body\" : \"" + message.GlucoseMeasurement.ValueInMgPerDl + " at " + message.GlucoseMeasurement.Timestamp + "\"," +
                                     " \"icon\" : \"icon\"," +
                                     " \"color\" : \"#FF4081\"}")
            });
```